# Can you turn off auto-complete/auto-correct in mobile Safari? It's awful for SO

Tags: mobile-safari, autocorrect

I have an iPad Pro with a Logitech keyboard. It is *almost* useable for day-to-day light work.

However, the auto-complete/auto-correct feature in mobile Safari is truly awful when posting to Stack Overflow. In particular, it keeps converting back-ticks (`) to abbreviations like "1st" or "10th". Is there a way to turn off auto-correct for a specific website?

I found several posts talking about how to disable auto-correct in the HTML of a website. I'm talking about as a user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn auto-correction off. But unfortunately not for specific apps or websites.

- Open the settings app
- General > Keyboards
- Turn Auto-Correction off